# Python, selenium robot drop down selection

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all data from a website called Correios, in this website, I need to handle some dropdowns which I'm having some issues with like: There's two dropdowns which have some dependency, I want to create a robot that passes through all the options for every item of both dropdowns and gets data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


chrome_path = r"C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
lista_x = []
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
driver.maximize_window()

dropdownEstados = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="estadoAgencia"]""")

optEstados = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='estadoAgencia']/option""")
optMunicipios = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="municipioAgencia"]/option""")
for valores in optEstados:
    encoded = valores.text.encode()
    valores.click()
    for municipio in optMunicipios:
        municipio.click()
```

There's two dropdowns, one that select States and the other select counties, the second one depends directly of the first one. I would like to know how can I pass trough all the counties options after selecting a state in a for, doing that for all states.

output:

```
selecting Estado ACRE
...selecting Municipio ACRELANDIA               
...selecting Municipio ASSIS BRASIL             
...selecting Municipio BRASILEIA                
...selecting Municipio BUJARI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPIXABA                 
...selecting Municipio CRUZEIRO DO SUL          
...selecting Municipio EPITACIOLANDIA           
...selecting Municipio FEIJO                    
...selecting Municipio JORDAO                   
...selecting Municipio MANCIO LIMA              
...selecting Municipio MANOEL URBANO            
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL THAUMATURGO     
...selecting Municipio PLACIDO DE CASTRO        
...selecting Municipio PORTO ACRE               
...selecting Municipio PORTO WALTER             
...selecting Municipio RIO BRANCO               
...selecting Municipio RODRIGUES ALVES          
...selecting Municipio SANTA ROSA DO PURUS      
...selecting Municipio SENA MADUREIRA           
...selecting Municipio SENADOR GUIOMARD         
...selecting Municipio TARAUACA                 
...selecting Municipio XAPURI                   
selecting Estado ALAGOAS
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your question?

Comment: Sure man, it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
time.sleep(3) #this time allows the page load all the elements
estadoList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
for index in range(1,len(estadoList.options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
    print("selecting Estado",select.options[index].text)
    select.select_by_index(index)
    time.sleep(2)
    municípioList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
    for index_b in range(1,len(municípioList.options)):
        select_b = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
        print("...selecting Municipio",select_b.options[index_b].text)
        select_b.select_by_index(index_b)
        time.sleep(2)
```

use the following in imports

```
 import time
```

Comment: When i run it, it start to repeat the municipios.Look at the output:

Comment: i'm going to add to the question the output

Comment: If you observe the output:
        After selecting all counties of ALAGOAS, it tried to print the next state "Amapá", but as it has a non utf-8 character, an exception has occurred.
        And it started selecting the counties of Amapá.

Comment: and how can i put it in utf-8?

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Anaconda jupyter notebook with Python 3, and it is printing the non utf-8 character.
See the below output.
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
**selecting Estado AMAPÁ**
...selecting Municipio AMAPA

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3. But even when you print the non utf-8 chacacter it gives the corect countie?

Comment: yes.  this is a part of output i got. 
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
**selecting Estado AMAPÁ**
...selecting Municipio AMAPA                    
...selecting Municipio CALCOENE                 
...selecting Municipio CUTIAS                   
...selecting Municipio FERREIRA GOMES           
...selecting Municipio ITAUBAL

Comment: Even when i use # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- the same error of repeting counties's given

Comment: If i just run the same code in anaconda, the error's going to be solved?

Comment: If you have more time to complete this project, then try anaconda. you will like it.